# Open Source/Free C# Platform Diagnosis Library (CPU, RAM, HDD etc.)

Tags: c#, wmi-service, performance-monitor

I'm writing an application which allows me to monitor various health parameters of a server system (CPU, RAM, HDD, Processes & Service Usage etc.) and then ties into a different system for data analysis. I could grab lots of values via PerformanceCounter or query WMI, but wondered if there is already some kind of free/open source library which contains a large amount of system diagnostic information retrievers that I could use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I tried something I saw on CodeProject that wrapped some WMI access in a single class (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WMI_Helper_Library.aspx).

Maybe that could help you... or at least a starting point.